# how to restart MySQL database in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I changed a table layout of MySQL database in AWS using phpMyAdmin.
I followed AWS instructions and restarted the database using EC2/Instances/My database/Actions/Reboot.
After that, I could not delete a record in the table for a while.
On the next day, I was OK to delete a record.

I wonder if I did not restart the database in correct way. I am new to database.
Did I do something wrong? Thanks for any advice. :)

Forget about the error.
I'd like to know how to restart a changed MySQL in AWS.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Were there any error logs showing that something happened when you tried to delete the record?

Comment: @Tim No. Right after pressing OK button, the screen(currently Browse) goes to Insert screen. And nothing happened.